# Restoration of SVN comments after a merge

Tags: svn, logging

After a branch had been merged back to the trunk in a subversion (version 1.6.11) repository I am no longer able to see the log comments which were associated with that branch from the trunk.  This particular branch existed on its own for quite some time there is a gap of several hundred log comments which are missing when `svn log svn://repo/trunk` is called.

The comments seem to be displayed when using `svn log -g`. However the log comments include the text "Merged via: rXXXX".

The more major issue is that I am unable to use the `-r` or `-l` options to limit output when using `-g` for those log comments within the range of this gap.  And if I try to use the `-r` option for the revisions before the merge without `-g` I get a blank log screen, so it seems it is all or nothing for the post-merge log comments.

I know the comments still exist (subversion saves everything), they are visible using `-g` and are visible by viewing the log of the branch which was merged to the trunk (likely incorrectly);

However, is it possible to fully restore these missing comments to the log for the trunk?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

The behavior you describe is normal, as in that the trunk log only shows the commit messages for trunk itself. If you need to access the commit message of a merged branch instead, your described approach was already correct: get the log directly from the branch.

Note that once you delete the branch, you also need to supply a peg revision when querying that branch's log. For example, if your branch `svn://repo/branches/foo` is deleted in revision 1000, you must use something like the following to access its commit messages:

```
svn log http://repo/branches/foo@999
```

Comment: I have read on peg revisions, but only briefly.  So even if the branch is deleted the log comments can still be accessed by supplying a peg revision?

Comment: Exactly. You just need to make sure you use a revision as the peg revision at which the branch existed (i.e. a revision after creation and before deletion of the branch).